# Put mitmproxy behind a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

I have a mitmproxy instance running on port `2222`. I want to put it behind a reverse proxy (like Nginx or Caddy), so I can use it as `mitmproxy.tld`. It seems that mitmproxy can't be accessed by anything other than `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, though I'm not sure about this.

`curl -x http://mitmproxy.tld:80 google.com -v` gives me a `500 Internal Server Error`

---

I have something that sort of works ---

```
stream {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $port {
            hostnames;
            proxy.history.* 2222;
            default '';
        }
        
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:1080;
        ssl_preread on;
        
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:2222;
    }
```

The problem is that there's no variable for the proxy host name, so I can't check if people are accessing the proxy from the right domain.

Answer (score 0):

By default `mitmproxy` and `mitmweb` only listen on localhost/127.0.0.1 but you can specify the host/interface it should listen on, for example if it should listen on all available IPv4 interfaces use `0.0.0.0`:

```
mitmproxy --listen-host 0.0.0.0
mitmweb  --listen-host 0.0.0.0
```

If you want additionally also listen on IPv6 use `::`

```
mitmproxy --listen-host ::
mitmweb  --listen-host ::
```

`mitmdump` by default already listens on all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces.